# Delphi strings + #32 control character

Tags: delphi

I've been asked to convert a delphi program to a C# program. Now i found this line:

```
Data := '!RW 65 '+ Data +#32+ CRC_16('!RW 65 '+Data+#32) + #10
```

I found that + #10 means Line feed but i cant find #32 anywhere. Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: AFAIK, that's a space. See [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: A websearch for Delphi #32 has the answer. Websearch is very useful.

Comment: #32 is the character with ASCII 32, i.e. a space character. The following is equivalent: `'!RW65 ' + Data + ' ' + CRC_16('!RW65 ' + Data + ' ') + #10;`.

Comment: Probably you don't know what the `#` syntax means. That's explained in the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements_(Delphi)#Character_Strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at an [ascii table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), you will find that it is the space character. It is a printable character, not a control character.